# Newton interpolation matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a function to interpolate polynomials with the Newton method, but I'm having some trouble.

```
function n = newtonInter(x, y)
n = length(x);
a = zeros(n,1);

for k = 0:n-1
       a(k) = y(k);
       for i = k + 1:n
           y(i) = (y(i) - y(k))/(x(i)-x(k));
       end
end
a(n) = y(n);
```

I get an error code in line 5, "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

I set x = [1 2 3 4] and y = [2 0 -10 -34]

Comment: Unlike `C`, `Java` etc, `Matlab` arrays are **not** [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), which means that you have to change your outer loop to `for k = 1:n` and, of course, do the necessary changes to the rest of your code

Comment: @sokin Thanks! changing it to k=1:n did the trick, however I'm getting the wrong answer :\, trying to figure out what to change for the rest of the code now. Edit: Figured it out! thanks again :)

Comment: It's OK. Glad I helped.